# How can I add quotation marks in CSV?

Tags: csv, go

I have a CSV file and want to add quotation marks (").

My CSV file:

```
comment_ID,comment_post_ID,product_SKU,comment_author,Comment
100,12505,B00E4MQODC,Elena, Nice Product
101,12505,B00E4MQODC,Jordan, Good Product
```

I want to change it to this (with comma - every column):

```
comment_ID,comment_post_ID,product_SKU,comment_author,Comment
"100","12505","SD010E4MQODC","Elena", "Nice Product"
"101","12505","CB0E4MQ12ODC","Jordan", "Good Product"
```

My code:

```
cwe := csv.NewWriter(cf)
cwe.Write([]string{"comment_ID", "comment_post_ID", "product_SKU", "comment_author", "comment"})

//Transfer Data To Comment CSV
for _, expose = range d {
        var record []string
        record = append(record, strconv.Itoa(int(cmtCounter)))
        record = append(record, strconv.Itoa(exp.ID))
        record = append(record, exp.SKU)
        record = append(record, exp.review[zmcoun])
        record = append(record, comment)
        cwe.Write(record)
    }
}

cwe.Flush()
```

I tried two ways but it's still not working:

```
`"`+variable+`"` //"""variable"""
Strings.Quote(variable) ///"""variable"""
```

Comment: The stdlib encoder adds quotes only when necessary. You should consider encoding the CSV manually instead of using the stdlib encoder.

Comment: @Melisa you can use this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12755#issuecomment-150670079

Comment: While this question is specific for GoLang I just added an answer to accomplish the task using any Python3, that requires no copy-pasting code, and do the correct quoting and escaping of inner quotes. So far, the 2 answers herefall short on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72046663/python-converting-non-conventional-csv-into-a-compatible-csv/72046815#72046815

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same and the csv writer from the std library is simple enough to modify to get it to do what we want in just a few lines to look like this.
https://gist.github.com/andrea3bianchi/16d42a277db7b3de43b2a316b7894dbd

If you diff it against the std library one https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/writer.go you'll see that I only added the flag

```
    ForceQuotes bool // True to add "" to every non-empty field
```

To the main struct and

```
if w.ForceQuotes {
    return true
}
```

To the fieldNeedsQuotes function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string formatting.

For example, instead of `record = append(record, comment)`, you could do

```golang
record = append(record, fmt.Sprintf("%v", comment))
```

Comment: it's not working, unfortunately. its same result

Comment: Then I am guessing the library is removing them somehow. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough to know why the library might be doing it.