# Converting non-conventional CSV into a compatible CSV

Tags: python, csv

I got this kind of CSV which is not an CSV. Let me explain it. The output has `column_name,value`.

e.g.

```
created_at,2022-02-10T16:53:49+01:00
updated_at,2022-04-28T00:35:30+02:00
timezone,Europe/Berlin
```

I need to convert it into a friendly csv for excel. So the required output will be:

```
"created_at","updated_at","timezone"
"2022-02-10T16:53:49+01:00","2022-04-28T00:35:30+02:00","Europe/Berlin"
```

I found a way using this code:

```
pd.read_csv('in.txt', header=None).T.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Which outputs a file like this:

```
created_at,updated_at,timezone
2022-02-10T16:53:49+01:00,2022-04-28T00:35:30+02:00,Europe/Berlin
```

That could be OK but no, the double quotes are missing on each of the lines and also the CR at each of those lines too. So when I open the CSV with the excel, go to DATA > TEXT TO COLUMN and try to order as if were a table, does not work because of the missing double quotes and the CR.

I need to process a 2MB file and I was trying to do it automatically but I didn't find a proper way to do it.

Comment: This question was already answered on StackOverflow for a GoLang implementation: https://StackOverflow.com/questions/68694271/how-can-i-add-quotation-marks-in-csv

Comment: This question was already answered on StackOverflow for a shellscript implementation:
https://StackOverflow.com/questions/17157850/how-can-i-add-quotation-marks-to-fields-in-a-csv-file

Comment: nope, if you see, the csv format is not the same, as the columns belongs to the rows not as a column name.

my format is Column, value, and not Column CR value comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using Pandas for some other thing, there is no need to use it for this situation: the stdlib `csv` module allows full control of the output formatting.

All you need in Python is:

```
import csv

with open("input_file.csv") as input, open("output_file.csv", "wt") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(csv.reader(input))
```

There is some indirection in the docs about all the formatting options, but they are at the end of the section on the CSV module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params

Comment: Hi Jsbueno, thanks for the reply, but your script is not working, says, ile "stringy.py", line 5, in <module>
    writer.writerows(csv.reader(input))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: fixed, the 'w' was missing on the output. Now it almost 90% working as it should but there is no carriage return at the end on the column headers and the value of the row. How I could add that on each of the lines?

Comment: The link at the end of the answer points directly to all formatting parameters that can be passed on the creation of `writer`, and that includes the `lineterminator` parameter.